# How to get previous year from day of week and week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have function get day of week and week from current day in mysql
It look like.

```
select 
   DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%U') as w,
   DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%w') as day_of_w;
```

It return w is 37 and day_of_week is 1. How to get correct value w is 37 and day_of_week is 1 of previous year.

I using

```
select 
   DATE_FORMAT(now() interval 1 year, '%U') as w,
   DATE_FORMAT(now() interval 1 year, '%w') as day_of_w;
```

But SQL cannot execute.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? I think you need a calendar table.

Comment: mysql version is 5.7. I missing +  before interval

Comment: "+ interval" is giving you date ahead .. if you want previous year, you need to use "- interval" .. but using "now() - interval 1 year" will only get you the same date as today just a different year. It's not certain that you'll get Week 37 and day of week 1. That's why I suggest that you have a calendar table - or generate a calendar table. Edit: Well, I think Thorsten answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function to turn a string into a date is `STR_TO_DATE`. If you want to get the date for week 37, day 1 in 2019, you could use

```
select str_to_date('37 1 2019', '%U %w %Y')
```

If you want the date for today's week and day number in last year:

```
select str_to_date(concat_ws(' ', date_format(current_date, '%U'),
                                  date_format(current_date, '%w'), 
                                  year(current_date) - 1),
                   '%U %w %Y')
```

Be aware though, that some years have a week 53 while others don't. If you run this query in a year's 53rd week, you don't get a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DAYOFWEEK(now()) day_of_week, week(now()) week from dual
```

your query has syntactical problem. you forgot +/- symbol

```
select DATE_FORMAT(now() + interval 1 year, '%U') as w
      ,DATE_FORMAT(now() + interval 1 year, '%w') as day_of_w;
```

Comment: select DATE_FORMAT(now() + interval 1 year, '%U') as w
      ,DATE_FORMAT(now() + interval 1 year, '%w') as day_of_w; 

=> it can get value from previous year with week and dayofwek ? It correct sql ? Why when i excute it same value current year

Comment: what are you trying to do? `now()` gives you `today now() - interval 1` year gives you last year today

Comment: Thanks you i have solution
I use select str_to_date('37 1 2019', '%U %w %Y')

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `DATE_ADD` function in `MYSQL` to change the date to last year.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR), '%U') as w
,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR), '%w') as day_of_w;
```

Result:

```
36  6
```

Current and last year date:

```
select now() as curr_yr_date, DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) as last_yr_date;
```

Result:

```
2020-09-14 07:13:24 2019-09-14 07:13:24
```

Comment: This result is valid for leap year as well :-)

Comment: The problem with this is that it gives you the same date in a previous year (e.g. 2019-09-14 for 2020-09-14) and not the day with the same week and day number as requested (e.g.  2019-09-16 for 2020-09-14, both being day #1 in week #37).